Free probability version of Poincaré Separation Theorem
Suppose $A$ is a $d \times d$ real positive semi-definite matrix, and $U$ is a $d \times n$ semi-orthogonal matrix such that $U^\top U = I_n$. Define $B = U^\top A U$. The Poincaré Separation Theorem states that the eigenvalues obey
$$
\lambda_i(A) \ge \lambda_i(B) \ge \lambda_{d-n+i}(A)
$$
where $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \ldots \ge \lambda_d$ denote the eigenvalues of $A$ in decreasing order, and $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \ldots \ge \lambda_n$ denote the eigenvalues of $B$ in decreasing order.
Now, I am wondering if there is a free-probability version of this theorem. Specifically, if $U$ is a uniformly random semi-orthogonal matrix and the eigenvalues of $A$ follow some limiting distribution $\mu_A$, can we determine a limiting eigenvalue distribution $\mu_B$ for $B$?
Formally, if
$$
A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}, \quad \lambda(A) \sim \mu_A, \quad U \sim \text{Haar}(V_{d,n}),
$$
can we find
$$
\lambda(U^\top A U) \sim \mu_B \, ?
$$
Informally speaking, given the Poincaré Separation Theorem, the eigenvalues of $B$ exclude the smaller eigenvalues of $A$. Thus, we can expect the orthogonal projection to act as a kind of "high-pass filter" for the eigenvalues of $A$. Are there any known mathematical results or theories about this projection in the context of random matrix theory or free probability?
